# Is it possible to create a RoomDatabase for Contacts?

Tags: android, android-room

It's pretty straightforward to make a "Contact" Room Entity and Room DAO, but how would you use them? For instance, would it be possible to point a RoomDatabase at Contacts.CONTENT_URI?

Comment: *Is it possible to create a RoomDatabase for Andriod Contacts?* No ... Room is using SQLite directly it is not using ContentProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would it be possible to point a RoomDatabase at Contacts.CONTENT_URI?

No, sorry. Room is for your own SQLite databases. It is not an object wrapper around arbitrary data sources (`ContentProviders`, Web services, etc.).